# NetworkError while trying to POST a JSON payload to localhost via HTTP

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, axios, fetch

Following situation:
I have a multiple linux systems with some simple python http (api) servers.
On the same systems there are firefox browsers running the web application via ssl opened from elsewhere (local network webserver).
The web application is trying to communicate with this local hosted python api server (only locally, within the same system).
So, the app is trying to send a post request on localhost / 127.0.0.1 / [::1] via http.
This is the mixed content situation, because app originally runs via SSL (hosted on other server). Firefox allows this when using 127.0.0.1, to use localhost i had to change the security settings (i just did it for test purpose).
And everything fails with following error:
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
test query:

```
fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:8080', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(data)}).then(response => {console.log(response);});
```

Axios intercepts an exception, but returned error response objects are null.
data is a very basic 3-field json object.

The problem is, these systems are running Firefox versions 57-60.
I can "successfuly" reproduce the same problem on my locally installed FF 60.2.2 on Windows 10, so this seems to be really the Firefox issue.

Newest Firefox versions however can communicate without any changes in JS code flawlessly (on Windows 10).
Python server accepts and supports CORS.

I have no way to update these browsers.

Now, i've made some tests with GET queries. And suprisingly they do work!
like:

```
fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:8080').then(response => {console.log(response);});
```

is successful.
and this:

```
fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:8080', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(data)}).then(response => {console.log(response);});
```

fails with:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

I would suspect the python server, but it works with last FF versions on Windows 10. In addition, in the Firefox developer tools i don't see in the network ANY localhost POST tries, but i see these test GETs like if the Firefox wouldn't even for some strange reason try to send a POST to local http. So maybe i am making somwhere an error - why the hell GET works and POST isn't even send in these older FF versions?

Any hint would be nice.

Comment: Just few cents to add - curl on the same system sends POST queries also flawlesly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it has to be this python api server and CORS support (eventually CORS compatibility between older and newer browsers).
Adding an option "mode: 'no-cors'" to my fetch query solved the problem